# Multibound ToolTips per ListView row

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, tooltip, multibinding

I want the information from cells of multiple columns displayed in a tooltip (also some calculation is needed).

This code only shows how to make a tooltip for each row of the listbox, what do I need to change?

```
<ListView>
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
<!--alle the columns and stuff-->
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind using a [MultiValueConverter](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/298950/Using-ValueConverter-and-MultiValueConverter-in-WP) and pass the columns you want.

Or you could add an extra property to each row that provides the calculated value and bind to that.

**EDIT**

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{local:ThingsToTooltipConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
            <Binding Path="Column1"/>
            <Binding Path="Column2" />
            <Binding Path="Column3" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Sorry but I need some more information (couldn't compile the *.csproj file). I don't know how to set the multibinding on the tooltip in xaml code. Article says codebehind works like IValueConverter so that shouldn't be the problem.